# How can I install Ubuntu on a 2007 Macbook Pro?

Tags: system-installation, 32-bit, macbook, intel-cpu

I have a 2007 Macbook Pro that is running 10.6.8. I'm actually using it now to ask this question. I also have an iMac running 10.13.6. I can't use my laptop because of its age and because I cannot update it any more, browsers won't work properly etc. I was advised to try Ubuntu.

As it stands now, I've got the `.iso` file and I've also converted it to a `.dmg` file by following the instructions from the Ubuntu site, however, I'm not very technical. I can follow instructions but when it comes to terminology, I don't know a thing!

I also burned a dvd from the iso file from my imac using Etcher. Reason is my computer will not recognise a USB stick to be bootable with. I've tried the terminal commands but they didn't work.

I inserted the dvd in the drive. It didn't mount on the desktop but also didn't give me any errors.

I restarted the computer and held down the Alt/Opt key.
I got the two choices and chose the CD however the CD said "Windows".
Screen went black and was then prompted with....

```
1  
2  
Select CD Rom Booty Type:_
```

Keyboard wouldn't let me type anything
After googling this, I was even more confused.

Had trouble trying to restart/shutdown computer so only way was to unplug it (battery is useless).

I tried again but this time alt/opt didn't give me the DVD to choose from - the dvd actually spit out at that point. So I booted to my macOS. Re-inserted the DVD but then got an error saying that the cd was unreadable: eject or ignore.

My mac specs are as follows:

Hardware Overview:

- Model Name: MacBook Pro
- Model Identifier: MacBookPro1,1
- Processor Name: Intel Core Duo
- Processor Speed: 2 GHz
- Number Of Processors: 1
- Total Number Of Cores: 2
- L2 Cache: 2 MB
- Memory: 2 GB
- Bus Speed: 667 MHz
- Boot ROM Version: MBP11.0055.B08
- SMC Version (system): 1.2f10
- Serial Number (system): W86180XAVJ3
- Hardware UUID: 00000000-0000-1000-8000-0016CB95FE84
- Sudden Motion Sensor:
- State: Enabled

This computer works great! It starts up beautifully, all the keys work. The CD drive is actually new (just installed a new one, the old one failed). I can't give this system up! I just can't use it because of outdated programs.

Answer (score 0):

Hey I think I might have a solución. I also have a MacBook pro from 2007 and even do I havent installed ububtu yet I have investigated and might have a solution.
I stubled across a YouTube tutorial that had a similar problem and solved it just by installing the 34 bit version of Ubuntu.
Link: https://youtu.be/ZJCv-2mIPsc
I hope it is usefull.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1240716)

Answer (score -1):

Apart from installing from CD or bootable pendrive there are couple of other option to work with Ubuntu in your system.

1. Use VMWare or Oracle VM software and install Ubuntu in it. Virtual Machines are best solutions for experimental setup.
   Link: https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/server-storage/vm/downloads/index.html
2. Use Live USB stick.
   Link: https://www.quora.com/How-can-I-use-Ubuntu-without-installing-it-on-my-laptop

Comment: The thing about Option 2 is that my computer will not recognise a USB stick as anything but a storage drive.

Comment: Option 1: Oracle website is confusing as all hell. LOL